# Use local files with MediaSource

Tags: javascript, html, node-webkit

I am trying to build a local video player in nwjs (node-webkit). I was able to play the local files by adding their path as the video element's src attribute, but now I want to make use of MediaSource and ,probably necessary, URL.createObjectUrl().

The problem is I haven't found any documentation that allowed me to achieve this, during my tests I am unable to append a new source to MediaSource as the local file. I tried direct paths and XHR requests, the closest I have been was with the XHR request of the file but I cannot convert the xhr.response into a usable item for my purpose, such as a objecturl.

For some reason just changing the src attribute directly each time a new video is selected causes the memory usage to grow constantly, which is why I would like to try doing this via the MediaSource api.

Since there's a lack of such information I would appreciate if anyone could help.

Comment: Some browsers, as a security precaution, block access to local files or behave very differently.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher This is not in a browser per se, this is in node-webkit which has lots of freedom since it uses node.js modules.

There are no problems with local file access, I even said that I could fetch the files with success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to discover how this could be done, first there needs to be a mediasource object with which you use URL.createObjectUrl to link to the video.src, and then you create a buffer on it. It is to that buffer that is appended the media which is loaded via XMLHttpRequest with the Content-type set as an arraybuffer.

Careful with big files, if you don't segment them and load everything at once it will eat your ram and even crash your application.